# jQuery toggle div with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, toggle

Simple html & jQuery

```
<label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" />Money</label>
<label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />Interest</label>

<div id="blk-1" style="display:none">
    ...
</div>
<div id="blk-2" style="display:none">
    ...
</div>

$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").each(function(i) {
        $(this).change(function(){
            $('#blk-1, #blk-2').hide();
            divId = 'blk-' + $(this).val();
            $("#"+divId).show('slow');
        });
    });
 });
```

The desired toggle effect does not work though. Clicking one radio box fails to hide the other.

Any Ideas?

Comment: but you are not hiding the other radio button in your code, you are just showing one of the divs?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Reqyx/ (As others noted, you don't need the `.each()`. In addition, you should declare your variable with `var`.)

Comment: and you don't have to use `.each()` there, you can write it as `("[name=toggler]").change(...)`

Comment: I tried it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" />Money</label>
<label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />Interest</label>

<div id="blk-1" class="toHide" style="display:none">
    money
</div>
<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">
    interest
</div>

$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
    });
 });
```

as in http://www.jsfiddle.net/eKFrW/

Comment: Great solution. It would be even greater if it also showed the div that is checked on onload

Comment: You can use this @MrRebel : 
`$("#blk-"+$("[name=toggler]:checked").val()).show();`

Comment: Why using the .click function? So there is a effect, when click again the selected item. Using [.change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) this function only executes, if there is a change in selection. Miss I something?

Comment: I agree with @sschoof. Using click might cause unexpected effects (e.g. ajax calls).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input:radio").click(function(){
    $("div").hide();
    var div = "#blk-"+$(this).val();
    $(div).show();
});
```

Online demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yLJPC/

Answer (score 1):

Heres what you want I think. To start I would make the first radio button selected and the first div visible. Then switching buttons would swap the divs

```
$("input:radio").click(function(){        
   $('#blk-1').toggle(); 
    $('#blk-2').toggle(); 
});
```