# Select between two different forms

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

I would like to build something like this: at start an empty page with only two radiobuttons. Lets say

```
<input type="radio" name=myradio value="1">one
<input type="radio" name=myradio value="2">two
```

There are also two forms

```
<form name="form1" action="..." method="post">     
    <input.../>
    <input type ="submit"/>
</form>

<form name="form2" action="..." method="post">     
    <input.../>
    <input type ="submit"/>
</form>
```

But at the start I dont want to show them! Only if the user is selecting one the radiobuttons. If the user goes "one" then show up form1 if the user is on "two" show up form2. Any ideas?

Ahm there is something else. If the user is changing between the two form, can I add some "cool" effects? You know not only make the on invisible and show up the other one. Something with more effects. Maybe at change make the one slowly invisible and then show up the other one slowly too? Some CSS3 options for that? Thank you

Comment: Have you heard of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? In any case, this requires javascript. Maybe it's possible with hacky, fragile CSS but your best bet is to use js.

Comment: No its new. And can I solve this problem just only with html/css without any other libs? I tought css3 and html5 are very "strong" and got solution for everything.

Comment: I don't think you could do this with only CSS

Comment: It's [sort of possible](http://jsfiddle.net/SfqQg/) to do in CSS only, but you really don't want to fight it (and that example is not usable at all). Just use javascript - it may be intimidating but you will have to embrace it at some point.

Comment: The idea related to bringing the forms to life at the selection of radiobuttons can be easily achieved by javascript, i guess. If you need help on that side, just say **YES**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, hide one of the forms with `style='display:none'`

Then write a script toggles the visibility of the forms on the `onChange` event of the radio buttons. I agree jQuery would make this very easy:
[jQuery toggle div with radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674020/jquery-toggle-div-with-radio-buttons)

Also, with jQuery its easy to make those 'cool' effects.

---

Without jQuery, check this example, not the most beautiful way, but functional:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggle(theform) { 
    document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "none"; 
    document.getElementById(theform).style.display = "block"; 
} 
</script> 

<body>

<form name="form1" id='form1' action="..." method="post" >     
    <input />
    <input type ="submit"/>
</form>

<form name="form2" action="..." method="post" style="display: none;">     
    <input />
    <input type ="submit"/>
</form>


<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" onclick="toggle('form1');"/>one
<input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2" onclick="toggle('form2');" />two
```

Do you understand how this works or do you need some explanation?

Comment: Edited the code to your sample, and also made it valid xHTML because you were missing closing tags and quotations marks

Answer (score 1):

Use onclick with a toggle javascript. The onclick will toggle the visibility. The javascript will actually perform the toggle, and the `style="display: none;"` actually hides it until the toggle is performed.

so for instance the html

```
<input type="radio" name=myradio value="1" onclick="toggle_visibility('form1');">one
<input type="radio" name=myradio value="2" onclick="toggle_visibility('form2');">two

<form id="form1" action="..." method="post"  style="display: none;">     
    <input.../>
    <input type ="submit"/>
</form>

<form id="form2" action="..." method="post"  style="display: none;">     
    <input.../>
    <input type ="submit"/>
</form>
```

and the javascript in the header

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if(e.style.display == 'block')
              e.style.display = 'none';
           else
              e.style.display = 'block';
        }
</script>
```