# Add jquery when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have two radiobuttons in one group.
The first is checked if you visit the page by 'checked' in html..

I want to use javascript to adjust some css (through javascript, not by adding a class).
So if the first is selected, I want a certain class to get a `display:none` and an other class a `display:block`, but when the second radio button is selected, I want the the same as with the other radio button only and vice versa.

My html is:

```
<li><input type="radio" name="kosten" id="maand" checked><label for="maand">per maand</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="kosten" id="jaar" ><label for="jaar">per jaar</label></li>
```

I tried some jquery but I'm really bad at it.

```
if ($('input#maand').is(':checked'){
$('.bedrag-jaar').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Some examples of the `div`s I want to show up and disappear.

```
<li><strong><span class="bedrag-maand">some text</span> <span class="bedrag-jaar">some other text</span></strong></li>
```

Do you have any idea how i can get this working?

Comment: Your `if` has a missing closing bracket. Is that a typo while posting here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674020/jquery-toggle-div-with-radio-buttons

Comment: @Harry it's not true. It's only the editor missed the last one. I tried to edit her code but it requires at least 6 characters to change. So i gave up.

Comment: @Dvir Harry is correct. The bracket is missing off the if clause.

Comment: @Moob Never mind somebody edited it. Any way it just was out of the editor. it's not imprtant :]

Comment: Its still wrong... `if(thisClauseShouldBeClosed{...`

Comment: @Dvir: I wasn't referring to the `}`, rather to the missing `)` after `(':checked')`. Without that the `if` loop won't work. So it is important :)

Comment: @Harry You right `)` is missing :]

Comment: Harry, thanks I didn't notice that
Tim, Why is this a post dyplicate? I researched a lot of topics but couldn't find any working solution that I actually understood..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $spans = $('span[class*="bedrag"]').hide();
    $('input[name="kosten"]').change(function(){
        $spans.hide();
        $spans.filter('.bedrag-' + this.id).show();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/US3tP/)

it can be done much powerful, if you can add an additional class to the `bedrag-*` elements like

```
<li><strong><span class="bedrag bedrag-maand">some text</span> <span class="bedrag bedrag-jaar">some other text</span></strong></li>
```

then

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $spans = $('.bedrag').hide();
    $('input[name="kosten"]').change(function(){
        $spans.hide();
        $spans.filter('.bedrag-' + this.id).show();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gFahm/)

Comment: Thank you very much!, I almost got it working.
I have only one problem left.
Because the first radio button is automaticly selected, I want bedrag-maand to show automaticcaly when visiting the page.
When I visit now it is not displayed.

I tried to adjust the 'var $spans = $('.bedrag').hide();' in your code to .bedrag-jaar but than it is fine by visiting the page, but when I click the second radiobutton both prices will show up.

Do you know a way to auto display the 'bedrag-maand' span before switching radiobuttons?

Comment: @Maartje see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gFahm/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/US3tP/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code and try this:

```
$( "input[type=radio]" ).on( "click",function(){
    if ($('#maand').is(':checked')){
        $('.bedrag-maand').css('display', 'block');
        $('.bedrag-jaar').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.bedrag-jaar').css('display', 'block');
        $('.bedrag-maand').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CM9RP/)